# Can we use rcharts to plot Grouped_Categories charts from Highcharts?

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I am really appreciate the rCharts package that being created to do many cool stuff, really like it a lot. Besides, i am very interested to use R to plot the grouped_categories charts (Highcharts) by blacklabel (refer to the link below).

https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories

Example of the grouped_categories in json format:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [{
        name: "Fruit",
        categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
    }, {
        name: "Vegetable",
        categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
    }, {
        name: "Fish",
        categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
    }]
}
```

Can you let me know is rCharts package able to do so? If yes, can you show me some simple example R code for the grouped_categories chart just for my reference?

appreciate and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi yes you can do this with `rCharts`, just use `addAssets` for include the grouped_categories JS lib.

```
library("rCharts")
h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1$chart(
  type = "column"
)
h1$series(
  list(
    list(
      data = list(4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18)
    )
  )
)
h1$xAxis(
  categories = list(
    list(
      name = "Fruit",
      categories = list("Apple", "Banana", "Orange")
    ),
    list(
      name = "Vegetable",
      categories = list("Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato")
    ),
    list(
      name = "Fish",
      categories = list("Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna")
    )
  )
)
h1$addAssets(js = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/master/grouped-categories.js")
h1
```

Et voilà

Comment: Hi Victorp, you are a life saver. With the guidance you gave here, i am able to produce the grouped_categories using rCharts. I never know the addAssets function, So, i copy your code above and give a tried but the Xaxis doesn't display in grouped_categories. I might need to do more research on this and learn how to use it.

Comment: But your idea gave me a very good inspiration. Since i am going to plot the grouped_categories chart in Shiny, i follow your idea, but i use tags$head(tags$script(src="grouped-categories.js")) right after showOutput in UI.R. Just need to make sure create a folder called 'www' at the same directory of the server.R & UI.R, then copy the js file into this folder will do. Now the grouped_categories chart is working in Shiny....thank you very much again! :)

Comment: You're right, this is the way to do it in shiny. If it doesn't work in RStudio maybe it's because you have a proxy. So open the Viewer panel in the browser it should work. Or add the `grouped-categories.js` file in the folder where `rCharts`  is installed, something like this : `...\R\win-library\3.2\rCharts\libraries\highcharts\js` and use this : `h1$addAssets(js = "highcharts/js/grouped-categories.js")`.

Comment: Victorp, you are right, it was due to proxy. I am glad to learn addAssets from you and also made the grouped_categories work in shiny. Appreciate your help once again!!!